# Codeigniter file upload doesnt change name and doesnt always upload file

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks

I'm looking for help with codeigniter 3.0.6. I made form to upload file and then change it's name. If i skip changing name instruction it sometimes upload images sometimes it doesnt, but when i turn it on it doesnt upload at all. 
This is my controller:

```
`
$this->load->model('car_model');

        if ($this->input->post('manufacturer')&&$this->input->post('model')&&$this->input->post('price')&&$this->input->post('body_style')&&$this->input->post('engine_size'))
        {
            $data['manufacturer']=$this->input->post('manufacturer');
            $data['model']=$this->input->post('model');
            $data['price']=$this->input->post('price');
            $data['body_style']=$this->input->post('body_style');
            $data['engine_size']=$this->input->post('engine_size');

            $query=$this->car_model->add_car($data);

            $query=$this->car_model->get_last_id();
            $number=$query->num_rows();
            $config['upload_path'] = './images/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png';
            $config['max_size']     = '10000';  
            $config['file_name']='zdjecie'.$number.'.jpg';
            $this->load->library('upload', $config); 
            $this->upload->do_upload('photo');
            echo var_dump($_FILES);
            echo br().'zdjecie'.$number.'.jpg';`
```

and form

```
    echo "<body>";
echo form_open_multipart('index.php/add_car/add');
echo "Producent:";
echo form_input('manufacturer');
echo br();
echo "Model:";
echo form_input('model');
echo br();
echo "Cena wynajmu za dzień:";
echo form_input('price');
echo br();
echo "Pojemność silnika(cm<sup>3</sup>):";
echo form_input('engine_size');
echo br();
echo "Rodzaj nadwozia:";
echo form_dropdown('body_style', $options);
echo br();
echo "Zdjecie:";
echo form_upload('photo');
echo br();
echo form_reset('reset','Wyczyść');
echo form_submit('send','Wyślij');
```

What should i change to make it work?

Im using xampp and file limit set in php.ini is set to 2mb

Comment: I don't use anymore the built in uploader in Codeigniter. Use http://image.intervention.io/ you can do a lot with this.

Comment: solution was to add this line 
$this->upload->initialize($config);
before do_upload line

Comment: It's nice you have found the solution. But I was not giving you any solution only the advise  to have a look at image intervention. You can do a lot of stuff with it.